# What would be the right domain for a function that takes time as a parameter?

Tags: functions

I want to define a function that takes a value which represents time and returns an integer. 
So when using it, the function would look something like $f(t)$

What is the right (or commonly used) domain for such a function?

$f:T \rightarrow Z$

What would $T$ actually be? (Note I don't want to discretize it in timesteps or anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ would be the set of times that you were considering.  If you were dealing with a set of times with a discrete timestep, then it would be something along the lines of $\mathbb{N}$.  On the other hand, the time could start at some initial time $a$ go continuously to some time $b$, in which case you'd have a domain of $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$.

In general, however, your domain can be anything you want, and just depends upon the context.  While it wouldn't be very clear what was meant, it could be represented by complex numbers.  Usually, however, it is a subset of the real line.

Comment: Yes, no need for complex numbers. I just wanted to know what is the most common way people use to represent a normal timeline

Comment: Usually the non-negative reals, so that 0 is the starting point and the function's graph represents the progression of a particle/price/number/etc over time.

Comment: Yes precisely what I am trying to model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually time would be a real, so your domain is (part of)$ \Bbb R$

Comment: So is it defined as something like $T$ and specified that $T \subset R$? Or is there a specific standard symbol?

Comment: If it is a limited span, it can be something like $(t_i,t_f)$